# Sources of Stability - What's the real rule?

Tags: gumshoe, fear-itself

In [*Fear Itself*](http://www.pelgranepress.com/gumshoe/), you have to select a Source of Stability for every 3 points you invest in the Stability trait. Sources may be personality traits, activities, or people. The rules state:

> You may not select more personality traits than you do people, or more activities than you do people.

The example (pg.29) then goes on to show a PC with 15 points of Stability who chooses a personality trait, an activity, is then compelled by the rules to choose a person, and then selects a second personality trait and activity.

This to me seems to directly contradict the rule. The PC has 2 activities, 2 personality traits, and only 1 person.

What's going on here?

Comment: Did the rulebook actually have an example showing only 2, 2 and 1? From the way you described it could be 2, 2, and 2. That would of course depend on whether you can choose more than 1 source of stability for every 3 points. Usually Robin Laws doesn't mess stuff like that up, but he has a very dense writing style that's direct, but not always as clear as it could be.

Comment: "The example is always wrong."

Comment: @migo - Yes, the example is **exactly** as I stated. I didn't want to quote the whole thing, but I think 7sided is probably right. As a designer, I have noticed how much harder it is to update examples than to tweak rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to locate the errata thread on the official forum. The answer is that the example is incorrect.

The errata thread does not provide a correct example, but the rule is pretty self explanatory:

You need a person *first*. Then you can select up to 1 of each of the others. If you need more, you'll need *another* person, and then you can select up to one more of each of the others.

So the example would have to have chosen 2 people plus a total of three personality traits and activities, with at least one of each of them. So if it's people/activities/personality traits, the sample PC could have gone: **2/1/2** or **2/2/1**.

Comment: So was it supposed to be 2 person and 1 activity or 1 personality trait, or was it supposed to be 2-2-2?

Comment: @migo - I think my expanded answer will address your question. It was supposed to be 2 people and a total of 3 of the others.